# Problem with dual boot in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows, uefi

Ok so I'm using windows 10 64bit on Acer Predator Helios 300, and I had 900GB in my D drive, in which I freed up 250 GB, then I installed ubuntu 18.04 using a pen drive(I checked files before installing, nothing was broken), I did a minimal install, without internet, there were no errors.

The first time I loaded up ubuntu everything worked flawlessly. the grub loader showed up, I was taken to the login screen, the OS booted up properly, everything else was proper, system time etc.

However, when I opened up windows, it worked fine too, but for some reason the **time it showed was incorrect**. After turning off when I tried to open Ubuntu again, It **froze on the login screen**(time was wrong here too), I tried again after force shutting it and pressed `CTRL+ALT+F2` this time without entering the password, it froze again.

Then I tried to open Ubuntu with advanced options on the grub menu, It booted up, with correct time without freezing. But when I opened windows again, the same problem happened.

I tried to turn off automatic time update on both OS, thinking that its a problem of **unmatched system clocks**, but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's connected only with clock then this should solve problem

[Time fix on dual boot](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/09/dual-boot-fix-time-differences-between.html)

---

### EDIT:

e.g. Leave windows unchanged and on Linux run follwing command:

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc 1
```

Then you can check the status with

```
timedatectl
```

Where should be displayed something like this

```
RTC in local TZ: yes
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/897813)

Comment: corrected with example

Comment: Hey man, I reinstalled it and tried these commands, the clock is working fine now. But it still freezes on login screen. I can still boot it in recovery mode, is there any way I can check why is this happening.